# Find parent element of a 'title' xml tag containing specific text using Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I wish to parse an xml file and extract the parent `<sec>` which contains a `<title>` matching a specific text using Python 3.7 &  ElementTree

```
    ...
    <sec id="s0010">
     <label>2</label>
     <title>Materials and methods</title>
     </sec>
    <sec id="s0015">
     <label>3</label>
     <title>Summary</title>
     </sec>

     ...
```

I was able to locate the title using ET:

```
for title in parent.iter('title'):
                        text = title.text
                        if(text):
                                if("methods" in text.lower()):
                                        print("**title: "+text+"****")
```

But how do I get the parent object (`<sec>`) of the title containing the text of interest?

Comment: You already have the *parent*.

Comment: You want the `<title>`?

Comment: Okay, there is a comparison also, what is the comparison string?

Comment: No.. I wish to find the <sec>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a (nested) iteration in 2 steps: on *sec* and then on *title*. Something like:

```py
for sec in parent.iter("sec"):
    for title in sec.iter("title"):
        text = title.text
        if text and "methods" in text.lower():
            print("**title: " + text + " **** sec id: " + sec.get("id", ""))
```

For more details, check [[Python 3.Docs]: xml.etree.ElementTree - The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree).

Comment: Thanks! this is it.. just need to close the print brackets ;)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was in a rush, and didn't run the code through the interpreter.